# Data structure to hold the contents of the CSV file

Tags: python, storage

This is the CSV file to be parsed in our program. This is one of many CSV files

> ID|TITLE|COMPANY|DATE|REV|VIEW_TIME
>
> id1|title1|company 1|2014-04-01|4.00|1:30
>
> id1|title3|company 2|2014-04-03|6.00|2:05
>
> id2|title4|company 1|2014-04-02|8.00|2:45
>
> id3|title2|company 1|2014-04-02|4.00|1:05

The catch as given in the assignment is as follows

> Your first task is to parse and import the file into a simple
>   datastore.  You may use any file format that you want to implement to
>   store the data. For this assignment, you must write your own datastore
>   instead of reusing an existing one such as a SQL database. Also, you
>   must assume that after importing many files the entire datastore will
>   be too large to fit in memory.  Records in the datastore should be
>   unique by ID, TITLE and DATE.  Subsequent imports with the same
>   logical record should overwrite the earlier records.

Since the data structure can not hold all the data in memory, then I have to look into more permanent storage solution. Writing to a file seems more suitable than any other solution, but herein lies the catch. If I have to overwrite the contents on the basis of ID, TITLE, and DATE, then I would have to load the entire content in memory, before overwriting it, which is not possible, according to the precondition.

**WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR**

What approach should I take? I am not looking for a code sample, but I am hoping that some has an idea on which data structure or file structure to use. Anything suggestions like `Use a stack or a list or a file structure is appreciated`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be under the impression that StackOverflow is a site where you post a problem and get some code in return. This is in fact not the case. Your question will most likely be closed or even deleted shortly. To prevent this from happening in the future, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [take a look at the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, [make yourself famlilar as to what is regarded as on-topic around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Hello, I am not asking for code snippets. I am asking for suggestions on what data structure to use like List, Stack or something. I will update my post.

Comment: Pythons [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module offfers two main options for representing csv data. Perhaps it would be a helpful to read those docs for ideas.